# How to create Whats App preview animation?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm wondering how to make a preview like WhatsApp, this is the demo:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBdvV.jpg

Seems like it's not Peek and Pop because we just need to do Long Press then it'll be shown.

Note: you can test on native iOS message app (incase you don't install WhatsApp, they have same animation)

Thanks

Comment: This is called a `UIContextMenuConfiguration`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is `UIContextMenuConfiguration` which supports `iOS13` onwards.

You can see a preview and menu when you long press on tableViewCell. You can display any `viewController` or any `customView` as menu's preview component.

I have displayed a viewController as preview.

```
// MainViewController is first ViewController and DetailsViewController is second ViewController
class MainViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var castNameArr = ["Professor", "Berlin", "Nairobi", "Tokiyo", "Rio", "Denver", "Mosco", "Requel", "Helsinki", "Arturo"]
    var selectedCast = ""
    var detailVc = DetailsViewController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        title = "Money Heist Casts"
        detailVc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailsViewController") as! DetailsViewController
        }
}
```

---

Using `contextMenuConfigurationForRowAt` method of tableView we can create menu and preview.

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, contextMenuConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, point: CGPoint) -> UIContextMenuConfiguration? {
        selectedCast = castNameArr[indexPath.row]
        let identifier = "\(indexPath.row)" as NSString

        return UIContextMenuConfiguration(
            identifier: identifier,
            previewProvider: makePreview) { _ in

                let optionOne = UIAction(
                    title: "Option 1",
                    image: UIImage(systemName: "arrowshape.turn.up.right")){ _ in
                        //This will get called when you tap on Option 1
                }

                let optionTwo = UIAction(
                    title: "Option 2",
                    image: UIImage(systemName: "book.fill")){ _ in
                        //This will get called when you tap on Option 2
                }

                return UIMenu(title: "", image: nil, children: [optionOne, optionTwo])
        }
    }

// This will return a viewController which we want to display as preview
    func makePreview() -> UIViewController {
        detailVc.castNameStr = selectedCast
        return detailVc
    }
```

---

Using `willPerformPreviewActionForMenuWith` method will get called when the interaction is about to "commit" in response to the user tapping the preview.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willPerformPreviewActionForMenuWith configuration: UIContextMenuConfiguration, animator: UIContextMenuInteractionCommitAnimating) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        print(configuration.identifier as? String)
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(self.detailVc, animated: true)
    }
}
```

---

This is DetailsViewController which is shown as preview

```
class DetailsViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var titleLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var castImgView: UIImageView!
    var castNameStr = ""
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        titleLbl.text = "This is \(castNameStr)"
        castImgView.image = UIImage(named: castNameStr)
    }
```

Download demo from [Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1rkxfKDUzZtDMufO36KhiV618deah6DYD)

[image]

For more details you can check here

https://www.raywenderlich.com/6328155-context-menus-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started

https://medium.com/better-programming/creating-a-context-menu-and-sf-symbol-in-swift-e45459f5f704